# HiveContext createDataFrame not working on pySpark (jupyter)

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-hive

I am doing an analysis on pySpark using the Jupyter notebooks. My code originally build dataframes using sqlContext = **SQLContext**(sc), but now I've switched to **HiveContext** since I will be using window functions.

My problem is that now I'm getting a Java error when trying to create the dataframe:

```
## Create new SQL Context.
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

After this I read my data into an RDD, and create the schema for my DF.

```
## After loading the data we define the schema.
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in data_header]
schema = StructType(fields)
```

Now, when I try to build the DF this is the error I get:

```
## Build the DF.
data_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_tmp, schema)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
/home/scala/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in _get_hive_ctx(self)
    690 
    691     def _get_hive_ctx(self):
--> 692         return self._jvm.HiveContext(self._jsc.sc())
    693 
    694     def refreshTable(self, tableName):

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I have been googling it without luck so far. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've build Spark by yourself, am I right? If this is the case can you provide some details about the method?

Comment: @zero323 Yes, I followed a tutorial that was very similar to this one: http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/10/31/install-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/. Does it looks like a config issue? I'm willing to reinstall if you have any advice on how to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HiveContext` requires binaries build with Hive support. It means you have to enable Hive profile. Since you use `sbt assembly` you need at least:

```
sbt -Phive assembly
```

The same is required when building with Maven, for example:

```
mvn -Phive -DskipTests clean package
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried `sbt -Phive assembly`, but now it is complaining about `Not a valid command: Phive`. Do I need to download anything or perform any other action before attempting the assembly?

Comment: I doesn't sound right. Are you sure there is nothing missing there? Do you have sbt installed? If not then you can use `build/sbt`. If you cannot solve this you can also try deprecated: `SPARK_HIVE=true build/sbt assembly`

Comment: I do have sbt installed, when I run the command it does starts compiling, but it fails after a couple of minutes. Here is the complete output log for sbt -Phive assembly: http://pastebin.com/yMDzk5WD Do you have any suggestion? I'm kind of stuck here without access to all the HiveContext functions.

Comment: Finally got it working! The issue is that I was doing the assembly with the version of sbt that I have installed on my machine, and not the one that came with spark. So the correct way to run it was:  `/home/scala/spark-1.6.1$sudo sbt/sbt -Phive assembly`. Thanks for the help.